# Windows Kill all processes starting with a text

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I am looking to create a .bat file to kill all the Windows processes that start with a text - say Dropbox.
Can someone please help?

I tried and found that only we can using a task id, but I need to find all the task ids corresponding to the set of processes that start with a keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using wildcards like "Powershell Get-Process -Name ex*"?